# How to encode a mixed-value-type dictionary to JSON in Swift 4.1

Tags: json, swift, swift4.1

The code below works in Xcode 9.2 (Swift 4.0) but gives an error in Xcode 9.3 (Swift 4.1).

```
let dict: [String: Any] = [
    "status_code": 5,
    "status_message": "message"
]

let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(dict)
                           // ^  generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
```

I've tried making the dictionary `[String: Encodable]`, and using a `typealias` to both dictionary types, with the same results. Swift doesn't let you specify the type in a generic call, so that gives a compiler error. What should this look like in Swift 4.1?

Comment: If you are looking for a solution then you should use a `Struct` instead of a `Dictionary`.

Comment: @LucaAngeletti I do use a struct for my actual code. This is in a unit test where I'm constructing an atypical response, so I wanted to keep it loosely typed. I could define an ad-hoc struct in the function if I needed to, but I'd like to use a dictionary if possible

Comment: `Encodable` is a protocol, not a type.

Answer (score 3):

### Is Dictionary Encodable?

In Swift 4.1 a `Dictionary<Key, Value>` conforms to `Encodable` only if `Key` and `Value` are `Encodable` themselves.

Examples of `Encodable(s)` dictionaries

```
[String:Int]
[String:String]
[String:Double]
```

Example of non `Encodable(s)` dictionaries

```
[String:Any]
[String:UIView]
```

So, how can you solve your problem?

### Struct

Using a model value is probably the best solution

```
struct Status: Codable {
    let statusCode: Int
    let statusMessage: String
}

let status = Status(statusCode: 45, statusMessage: "message")
let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(status)
```

Comment: But if that's the only reason, then why doesn't `[String: Encodable]` work?

Comment: @Dov Encodable isn't a concrete type so it can't be used

Comment: @Jeremiah Thanks, I guess I didn't find it obvious that the values in a dictionary have to have a concrete type

Comment: How would you handle a dynamic list of properties in this scenario? For example what if the statusMessage above wasn't required? With a dictionary, you'd simply leave it out but I don't see how that's possible in a struct.